# How to tell a Homebrew formula to only symlink files under bin?

Tags: homebrew

I'm packaging a java app as a Homebrew formula.

I've got this in my formula

```rb
  def install
    bin.install "bin/my-app"
    lib.install Dir["lib/*.jar"]    
  end
```

It works fine, but it ends up symlinking all the jar files into `/usr/local/lib/`.
I see that the [keg_only](https://rubydoc.brew.sh/Formula.html#keg_only-class_method) option. However that will also prevent `bin/my-app` from being symlinked into `/usr/local/bin`.

Is there an option for me to say, "Install the bin as you normally do, but these libs need to only live in the Cellar for my app."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer at the [Homebrew forum](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/symlink-only-some-files/8058)

> Consider installing the JARs in libexec instead:
>
> ```
> libexec.install Dir["lib/*.jar"]
> ```
>
> and adjust the necessary paths in `my-app` (I assume it’s a typical
> Java launcher script). That’s a fairly common pattern in Java
> formulas.

This is what I have now

```rb
  def install
    bin.install "bin/my-app"
    libexec.install Dir["lib/*.jar"]

    inreplace "#{bin}/my-app", '/lib/', '/libexec/'
  end
```